Vite Error : FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
I'm encountering a "JavaScript heap out of memory" error when running npm run build on my Node.js project. The build process works fine during development (npm run dev), but it fails during production build with the following error:
transforming (820) node_modules/three-mesh-bvh/src/core/cast/shapecast.js
<--- Last few GCs --->
[1597:0x618f000]    16333 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 456.2 (468.1) -> 455.7 (466.6) MB, pooled: 0 MB, 587.81 / 0.00 ms  (+ 52.6 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 679 ms) (average mu = 0.212, current
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
1: 0xe1eff7 node::OOMErrorHandler(char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
2: 0x121a420 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
3: 0x121a6f7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, v8::OOMDetails const&) [node]
4: 0x144a235  [node]
5: 0x1463aa9 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
6: 0x1438178 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
7: 0x14390a5 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
8: 0x1411cee v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
9: 0x18732fc v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x1f29576  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
Steps Taken to Resolve:

Increase Node.js Memory Limit:
I attempted to increase the memory limit using the --max-old-space-size flag in the build script. Here is the updated package.json:

"scripts": {
"build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production",
"dev": "webpack serve --mode development"
}

Set Environment Variable:
I also tried setting the NODE_OPTIONS environment variable before running the build command.

(Linux--)
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
npm run build
Project Configuration:
Node.js
NPM
Webpack
Operating System: (Ubuntu 20.04)
Despite increasing the memory limit, the build process still fails. I'm seeking advice on any additional steps I can take to resolve this issue or any potential optimizations for the build process.
